# Bug in Wolfram Cloud (12.1.2)

Tags: wolfram-cloud

On Wolfram Cloud, there are some bugs. Like this one:

```
In[14]:= a=first;
b=second;
f=head;
Trace[f[a,b]]

Out[17]= {}

In[8]:= $Version

Out[8]= 12.1.2 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (September 9, 2020)
```

[image]

Comment: [Works as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpFnd.png) in 12.1.0 (using https://develop.open.wolframcloud.com/app/view/newNotebook?ext=nb).

Comment: Yes this is a known issue and will be fixed in the upcoming cloud release  version 1.57 ($CloudVersion). Thanks for reporting.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using Wofram Cloud application on iPhone. So I need to wait for the new cloud release?

Comment: There does not seem to be a question here that is being asked.

Comment: Yeah, the question was about Trace and friends stopped working on cloud.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We recently pushed a new cloud release C1.57 which fixes this issue.

[image]